# Is it possible to run code after very view has been loaded into the DOM?

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a facebook-tab page in angular. Because it's facebook I need to run some code every time the view is updated and DOM is fully loaded. I have found

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
```

But it seems to load before the DOM is done?